# Getting symbols parameters using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, arcgis-engine

I have FeatureClasses (point, line and polygons) with symbology in cartographic representation. How I can get each symbol's parameters (e.g. for polyline: width, colour, style)?
[image]

```
Dim featureClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass('feature_name')
Dim featureLayer As IFeatureLayer = New FeatureLayer
featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureClass
Dim gfl As IGeoFeatureLayer = featureLayer
Dim pLegInfo As ILegendInfo = featureLayer
'Dim pLineSymb As ICartographicLineSymbol = TryCast(pLegInfo.LegendGroup(0).Class(3).Symbol, ICartographicLineSymbol)
```

pLineSymb type is IMultiLayerLineSymbol, so

```
Dim pLineSymb As IMultiLayerLineSymbol = TryCast(pLegInfo.LegendGroup(0).Class(3).Symbol, IMultiLayerLineSymbol)
MsgBox("Color " & pLineSymb.Layer(0).Color.RGB)
MsgBox("Width " & pLineSymb.Layer(0).Width)
```

Color and width i get, but line has dashes

Comment: Maybe its not a multilayerlinesymbol but a [hashlinesymbol](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IHashLineSymbol.htm)?

Comment: I check with TypeOf (ICartographicLineSymbol, IHashLineSymbol, MarkerLineSymbol, ISimpleLineSymbol, IPictureLineSymbol, IMultiLayerLineSymbol):
If TypeOf pLegInfo.LegendGroup(0).Class(3).Symbol Is ICartographicLineSymbol Then
    ...

Comment: What exactly is it about the dashed line you want, the dash length or dashed frequency?

Comment: Your screen shot is from the representation editor, you might be barking up the wrong tree here, maybe look at IRepresentation https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//0025000007r6000000 to get the override symbology. The stroke pattern is an ITemplate https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//001w00000376000000, cast from ICartographicLineSymbol cast from ILineSymbol.